# Is there a technique to wrap a .NET Core library as a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, .net-core, wrapper, multiplatform

We've built some .NET Standard / .NET Core libraries that are able to target multiple platforms (linux, macOS, windows). We have a need to wrap the final assembly in Ruby, so that we may expose this functionality to the Ruby community as well.

I'm asking if there are any known tools, patterns, etc. used for this scenario?

We would like to maintain the bulk of our library in the .NET code, but be able to ship this in a wrapper, of some kind, for Ruby too.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: @RobertColumbia -  I removed the word "tool" from the title. I don't believe this is off-topic at all

Comment: Maybe it would help. Ruby https://github.com/ffi/ffi  gem allows to include C libraries.

Comment: Well I would have suggested `IronRuby` but Microsoft did a great job of killing that project. Chances are you would need a com wrapper for you library and then use `Fiddle` (a standard lib) or `ffi` as mentioned

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It seems like ffi would help, I'm just trying to connect all the dots so that someone knows the exact process to do this - including me ;)

Comment: Also posted here: https://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/how-would-one-wrap-a-net-core-lib-for-ruby/3027